# On ubuntu 18.04.1 server LTS virtual machine,the disk can not be mounted when the disk hotplugging

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, disk, udev

I had write a rules file in /etc/udev/rules.d , it will be used to process the disk event from kernel ，and it will be execute the other shell script to implemented automatic mount the disk.

When i add disk for virtual machine , it can not be mounted(write mounted rule in /etc/fstab and execute 'mount mountpoint'), the error message is 'mount point does not exist'. but I'm sure that the mountpoint is exist , because i create it before execute mount command , and mkdir cmd is execute successed.when it executed failed,i run 'mount -a' in cmdline, the disk will be mounted correctly.

Stay the same rules file and shell script , if i use the systemd.mount , it will be mounted successed directly;

Comment: I'm so sorry for my carelessness , it's not error when i execute 'mount mountpoint' , it had execute successfully.but when i execute 'df -Th' , i still can't find my disk is mounted;